# How can I filter between two models?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. One is a Partner. Another is Contact. Partner is the companys information. Contact is a contact for that company. How can I get a list of contacts from a company by comparing the name of the company to the foreign key partner which is who the contact belongs to.

I have tried using querys but the result was not what i expected.

```
class Partner(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):

    name = models.CharField(blank=False,
    help_text="Name of the role or function", 
    max_length=64,
    verbose_name="Partner Type", )

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
    'self',
    blank=True,
    help_text="Parent Company name (if necessary)",
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    max_length=200
    )

class Contact(ContactModel, TimeStampedModel):
        partner = models.ForeignKey(
        Partner,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="contacts",)
```

Urls.py

```
from .views import (
    ContactsListView,
    ContactsDetailView,
    ContactsCreateView,
    ContactsUpdateView,
    ContactsDeleteView,
)
from . import views

app_name = 'contacts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ContactsListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ContactsDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('new/', ContactsCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', ContactsUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
     path('<int:pk>/delete', ContactsDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    ]
```

What i want is a list of contacts belonging to that company.

Lets say the company name is Shell.
on The contact i would fill out the partner being shell. and i want to query all the contacts shell has.

Edit: meant contacts not partner.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the related contacts for partner instance by using the following line:

related_contacts = partner_instance.contact_set

Answer (score 0):

You can get a queryset that contains all the related `Contact` objects to a specific `Partner` object like this:

```
related_contacts = Contact.objects.filter(partner="pk of Partner model you want all the contacts of")
```